# PHP: Update JS file with edited row

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have the following AngularJS file called

> productFactory.js

with a list of products and their details and I want to update 1 of the products.

```
"use strict"; 

var productFactory = angular.module('productFactory', []);

productFactory.factory('productFactory', function () {

var productFactory = {};

productFactory.products = [
    {
        productId: 1,
        name: "Product1",
        category: "Urban",
        desc: "Lorem Ipsum",
        image: "placeholder1.png;placeholder2.png;placeholder3.png",
        price: 30,
        qty: 6,
        variation: ""
    },
    {
        productId: 2,
        name: "Product2",
        category: "Street Wear",
        desc: "Lorem Ipsum",
        image: "placeholder1.png;placeholder2.png;placeholder3.png",
        price: 40,
        qty: 10,
        variation: "6,7,8,9,10,11,12"
    }
];

return productFactory;
});
```

In PHP I can run this script to write to the file

```
<?php
$script="SOME_CONTENT";
$fileName="productFactory.js";
file_put_contents($fileName, $script);
?>
```

How do I update just one of the products by it's 'productId'?

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to store products in some database (it could be simple JSON file which you have in `productFactory.products` variable.

If they were stored in JSON, you would load the file in PHP, parse it to an object with `json_decode($str);`, then edit what you want in that object and after that just convert it back to JSON string with (`json_encode($obj);`).

If you store them in a database like MySQL, the PHP processing would be simpler I think (simply call an UPDATE query for given product id).

PHP example for processing edit request:

```
$path = "/path/to/products.json";
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$json = json_decode($string);

foreach ($json as & $product) {
    // process only correct product
    if ($product->productId !== $_POST['productId']) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($_POST as $key => & $value) {
        // here should be some data validation probably
        if (isset($product[$key]) {
            $product[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}

$newData = json_encode($json);
file_put_contents($path, $newData);
```

Comment: Yes, MySQL would be simpler and I could use PDO for that. I'm trying to build the entire site in AngularJS. I can create a JSON file and attach it to the productFactory.products variable. How then do I then edit the JSON file? What's the simplest PHP script? The new product details will be sent to the PHP file as POST data and I need to loop through the JSON and update the specific product details by its productId.

Comment: I added a simple example to do this, see the edited answer